# C# Print list of string array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

How do I print a list of string arrays? I can do it from `string[]` using `Console.WriteLine`, but if I do that for a list with `foreach` it just prints out `System.String[]`. How do I write an index when using a `foreach`?

Comment: Use the index and print it

Comment: if you want to print array values, you cannot just pass array to `Console.WriteLine` you should either print each item of array separately or convert array to string and then print that string. E.g. with `String.Join(",", yourArray)`

Answer (score 52):

The simplest way to achieve this is:
using **String.Join**

```
string[] arr = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", arr));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

So you have *list of string arrays*, like this:

```
 List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>() {
   new string[] {"A", "B", "C"},
   new string[] {"1", "2"},
   new string[] {"x", "yyyy", "zzz", "final"},
 };
```

To *print* on, say, the `Console`, you can implement *nested loops*:

```
 foreach (var array in data) {
   Console.WriteLine();

   foreach (var item in array) {
     Console.Write(" ");
     Console.Write(item); 
   }
 }
```

Or `Join` the items into the single `string` and then print it:

```
 using System.Linq;
 ...

 string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, data
   .Select(array => string.Join(" ", array)));

 Console.Write(report);
```

Or *combine* both methods:

```
 foreach (var array in data) 
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array));
```

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
var strArray = new string[] {"abc","def","asd" };
strArray.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] arr = new string[2]{"foo","zoo"}; // sample Initialize.

// Loop over strings.
foreach (string s in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

The console output:

```
foo
zoo
```

Answer (score 0):

In a string array to get the index you do it:

```
string[] names = new string[3] { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };

int counter = 0;
foreach(var name in names.ToList())
{
 Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString() + ":-" + name);
 counter++;
}
```